# Probability of Random Numbers in a Table Summing to $10$

Tags: probability

Assume a table with dimensions $n$x$n$. In each of the $n^2$ spaces, a random number ($m$) such that $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1\leq m\le9$ will be placed. My question is two-fold:

1. What are the odds that any two numbers next to each other along the cardinal directions (ie, vertically and horizontally) will have a sum of $10$?
2. What are the odds that the whole table will be filled with numbers that sum to $10$ with at least one of its neighbours?

(If it helps, assume that $10 \le n \le 1000$. Generalisation is appreciated, but specific answers are also okay!)

I'm not very good at probability, but I know that the first square (take the upper-left, for instance) in the table would have $9$ possible numbers and the square right next to it will have only $1$ possibility each to make the $10$. We could then move to $(2,2)$ in the table and repeat the process. However, if the number in $(2,2)$ is the same as the number in $(1,1)$, then it already meets the criteria for the puzzle. If we expand this outwards, we have found one possible solution out of the $9^{n^2}$ possibilities. I don't know how to solve it, necessarily if we were to start, say, at $(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: The $0$ can not appear anywhere.  Q1.: Without loss of generality, the two numbers are in the same row, and the leftmost number is $1$. Q2.: Incomplete beginning idea: suppose that in the leftmost column, the first row has a $1$ and the second row has a $2$.  For the moment, assume (**wrongly**) that no number in the second row *pairs* (i.e. is equal to $10$) with either of the numbers directly above it or directly below it.  Then, the first and second row are fixed, in that the first row must be $1, 9, 1, 9, \cdots$ and the second row must be $2, 8, 2, 8, \cdots$.

Comment: I've updated the question to exclude $0$ and made edits.

Comment: For Q2, an $n \times n$ square can be randomly populated in $9^{(n^2)}$ ways.  My first try would be to use the computer (e.g. write program in Java, C, or python) against each value of $n \in \{2,3,\cdots, 8\}.$  For each value, I would have the computer determine $f(n) = $ the number of placements (out of $9^{(n^2)}$) that are satisfactory.  Obviously, you **can not** have the computer  cycle through (for example) $9^{(64)}$ possible placements.  But what you can do, is have the computer reject any placement *at the time of violation*. ...see next comment

Comment: For example, if $n=8$, there are clearly $9^8$ possible placements of the first row.  Then, starting in the second row, if in any column, the number in the first row does not pair with either of its horizontal neighbors, then it must pair with its vertical neighbor.  This implies that for most of the $9^8$ possible first row placements, the entire second row will be fixed.  This will then  **fix** each successive row.  The main idea is to try to look for a pattern, as you compute $f(2), f(3), \cdots, f(8)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: The overall idea is to try to form a hypothesis based on the pattern uncovered by your examining $f(2), f(3), \cdots, f(8)$, and then trying to analytically prove your hypothesis.

Comment: Still trying to parse the meaning of "What are the odds that the whole table will be filled with numbers that sum to 10 _with at least one of its neighbours_?"

Comment: @BruceET It means that of the $9^{(n^2)}$ possible configurations, in how many of these configurations is the following true:  For each of the $(n^2)$ cells, the cell  *pairs* with at least one of its horizontal or vertical neighbors.  Here, two cells *pair* if and only if the numbers in the two cells sum to $(10)$.

Comment: There are a couple problems with your question that have not been addressed. First you say that the numbers are picked "randomly", but that is not sufficient. Rolling a 100-sided die with a single "1" and 99 "8"s will give you random numbers, but not distributed as you want. You should say "picked uniformly at random" if you want all digits equally likely (or some equivalent phrase). Second, the answer to question (1) as stated is $\frac 19$, since if you give me any two squares, that is the uniform distribution probability of them adding to $10$. Do you mean "some two adjacent squares"?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Agree with your comment.  Seems reasonable to presume that "picked uniformly at random" represents the OP's intent.  Also, seems reasonable to presume that Q1 is intended as an appetizer to kickstart the student's thinking, and that intended answer to Q1 is $(1/9)$.

Comment: @user2661923 - My first comment was just to point out to the user that "random" is more general than they thought. That the intent was uniform distribution is indeed almost certain. For question (1), though, I am not sure about the intent. Was it a simple kickstart question as you say, or has the question been miscopied/misconstructed, and the intent was "probability that there is some pair of adjacent squares whose sum is 10". But I was wrong in saying the answer is $\frac 19$. Because it asks for "odds", not "probability", the answer is "$1:8$" if the question is correctly framed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: As I understood, you're asking of the probability that in the table that we get every two neighbours (vertically or horizontally) will add up to 10.

If (1,1) contains a number $a$, then (1,2) and (2,1) must contain $(10-a)$, then (1,3), (2,2) and (3,1) must contain $10 - (10-a)$ = $a$ again , and so on, forming a chessboard pattern. As you can see, the number in (1,1) determines the whole table, so there are 9 total possible tables that satisfy our condition (for each starting number from 1 to 9).

Then the probability that every two neighbours in a random table will add up to 10 is: 9 over the total number of possible tables which is $9^{(n^2)}$.

Thus, for $n \geq 2$:
$$P = \frac{9}{9^{(n^2)}} = 9^{(1-n^2)}$$

---

Q2: I am going to attempt to calculate the probability for $n = 3$ by hand.

To start off, I will represent each table cell with a dot, and connect two neighbouring dots along the cardinal directions if they sum up to 10, and not connect them if they do not.

[See this picture for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEV5O.jpg).

So we get a way to represent the connections in any table visually. Notice also that [this pattern is impossible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMaAO.jpg). Thus, as long as the dots arranged in a 3x3 table do not contain such patterns, they represent the connections of an existing 3x3 table of numbers.

Now, like in Q1 I will calculate the number of tables that satisfy our condition and then divide it by the total number of possible tables ($9^{(3^2)}$).

The central dot can be connected to its neighbours in 15 different ways: [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjrQ0.jpg) (I've grouped them into 5 categories by rotational symmetry).

I've selected one representative from each category and constructed [all possible variants that satisfy our condition with these representatives as central dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFBRg.jpg).  Notice that to get all the variants that satisfy our condition it's enough to rotate all the members of the groups 1, 2, 4 by 90° thrice, and of the group 3: by 90° once. (Because of the rotational symmetry of these groups.)

Now I will calculate the number of actual tables (populated with digits from 1 to 9) that satisfy our condition AND are represented by one of these variants. [This picture will be helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSGM6.jpg):

- If there is 1 piece (i.e. there exist paths from any dot to any other dot) - there are 9 ways to number this piece. Thus, there are exactly 9 possible tables that can be represented by such a connection of dots.
- If there are 2 pieces - then they are definitely "touching" or are "adjacent to" each other (i.e. there exist two dots that are neighbours and that belong to different pieces), so while the first piece can be numbered in 9 ways,  only 8 ways are left to number the second piece in order for it to remain separate from the first one. So there are $9\cdot8 = 72$ possible tables.
- If there are 3 pieces and all of them "touch" each other - then there are 9 ways to number the first piece, 8 left for the second one and 7 for the third. So there are $9\cdot8\cdot7 = 504$ possible tables.
- If there are 3 pieces but 2 of them do not "touch" each other - then there are 9 ways to number the first piece, 8 left for the second one and 8 for the third. So there are $9\cdot8\cdot8 = 576$ possible tables.
- If there are 4 pieces and 2 of them do not "touch" each other - then by the same logic there are $9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot7 = 3528$ possible tables.

Now, summing it all up and multiplying by $4$ (for groups 1, 2, 4) and by $2$ (for group 3):

Group 1: $\, 4 \cdot (3528 \cdot 5 + 504 \cdot 12 + 72 \cdot 4) = 95,904$

Group 2: $\, 4 \cdot (504 \cdot 4 + 72 \cdot 4) = 9,216 $

Group 3: $\, 2 \cdot (576 \cdot 7) = 8,064 $

Group 4: $\, 4 \cdot (72 \cdot 3) = 864 $

Group 5: $\, 9 $

Then the total number of 3x3 tables that satisfy our condition is:

$$ 95,904 + 9,216 + 8,064 + 864 + 9 = 114,057 $$

Finally,

$$ P = \frac {114,057} {9^{(3^2)}} \approx 0.0002944 \approx 0.03\% $$

I feel like this probability will dwindle down to $0$ quite fast with growing n. The probability for $n = 2$ that I've got by a similar (but easier) process is $ \frac {72 + 72 + 9} {9^4} \approx 0.02332 \approx 2.3\% $

---

P.S.

- I did not check this with a computer program so there might be some mistakes, but I tried not to make any.
- Where are these questions from? It might be easier to find a solution if I know the topic of this problem (if it is from a textbook).
- This method of representing tables with connected dots generalizes to larger tables, but then you also need to check that 9 numbers is enough for assigning values to different touching pieces. (For example, it may be impossible to construct a table corresponding to some specific arrangement of dots with 10 different pieces all "touching" each other. By [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) there simply may be not enough numbers from 1 to 9 to prevent all the neighbouring cells of these pieces from summing up to 10, so some of the pieces will HAVE TO BE a single piece.)

Comment: Thank you so much! The question came about in my own mind (it may have posited before, but I'm not sure), because I got an advert for a game where you have to find numbers in a grid that sum to 10. I tried toying around with it a bit on Excel using the RNG formula, but I wasn't going to rely on that. I think the game uses a 10x10 grid, and manually generating all $9^{100}$ tables didn't seem like a good use of my time XD. I figured there'd be a mathematical way to do it, and it seems you've done it!